# Can I use multiple ilike for the same field in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a class & I am using createCriteria to fetch the record.

```
DomainClass.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {
...
        ilike("field", value.encodeAsHTML() << "%") 
        ilike("field", value << "%") 
}
```

So it should fetch records matching for both

Comment: Have you tried? If you had tried I suspect you would find it does work.

Comment: I tried it but it's not fetching any record.

Comment: Have you logged the SQL statement that is being used to see why it's not matching?

Comment: hmm... right. Let me check that.

Comment: it generates text ilike 'sub2%' and text ilike 'sub1%'.
 but I want text ilike 'sub2%' or text ilike 'sub1%'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutliple ilikes work just fine in a criteria. However, based on your comments it sounds like you are looking for an OR instead of an AND and you can do so like this:

```
DomainClass.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {
...
    or {
        ilike("field", value.encodeAsHTML() << "%") 
        ilike("field", value << "%") 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it ...

```
or {
      ilike("field", value.encodeAsHTML() << "%") 
      ilike("field", value << "%") "%")
}
```